# Program File Not to Use AppData Folder on Download

Tags: excel, appdata, vba

I have an Excel program which, if not already on the hard drive, downloads a .exe file from a website and saves it to the user's computer for use later on.

Though we download the file directly to the hard drive (or whichever drive was specified), a copy is always downloaded into the AppData folder, which often triggers antivirus software to reject it.

Is there any way to prevent the file from downloading to the AppData folder?

Comment: Add the VBA download code into the question

Comment: Into the plain `AppData` folder or into a subfolder of `AppData`? Because there are `Temp` folders inside `AppData` which are normal to be used on downloads. And if this triggers your AntiVirus this is not because it is in a specific folder like `AppData` but probably because the exe file triggers AntiVirus in **any** location?

Comment: Robin, the code is really long, but the download line is:  L = URLDownloadToFile(0&, UrlFileName, DestinationFileName, 0&, 0&)  where the DestinationFileName is a name on my C drive.

Comment: Peh, it is in a subfolder of the AppData folder.  It may trigger AntiVirus in any location, as you suggest.  One of our client's IT teams suggested that the AppData folder may be a trigger.

Comment: Though it sounds very simplistic, recent research showed us that the best way to avoid triggering antivirus was by making sure that the program was digitally signed.  Once we did that, the AppData did not seem to matter any longer.